# Implement inline help/guided tour for SAPUI5 apps

Tags: sapui5

I'm searching for a way to create a sort of inline help / guided walkthrough tour to explain certain elements/sections displayed on an SAPUI5 apps. I was checking examples, e.g. [intro.js](https://introjs.com/) and others (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/328/top-10-best-tour-website-guide-javascript-and-jquery-plugins). How would this work with xml views? Anyone has an idea or can point me to a resource? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI5Lab community has a custom library for guided tours, see [here](https://ui5lab.io/browser/index.html#/Samples/openui5.tour).
This library uses UI5 controls, so you could either use this library for your project or check the source code for some ideas on how to implement a UI5 native tour yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Voyager, for the tip. Interesting indeed.

Comment: One more question @Voyager - as an alternative to a guided tour. Do you also know if there is an xray like experience available for UI5 (which is more lightweight and easier to implement), i.e. I click a button and then some parts of the app are highlighted and can be clicked to get more information in a pop-up or suchlike.

Comment: I've never done something like this myself. I know that jQuery provides functions for animation. Maybe give it a try: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks, Voyager, for your input!